# Trying to SVN Checkout Open Source BitSharp Library

Tags: svn, bitsharp

I am having some trouble trying to checkout the [BitSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/Bitsharp) source code using SVN.  When I try to checkout http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/bitsharp/src, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included - I get the message:

> Repository moved permanently to
>   '/viewvc/trunk/bitsharp/src/'; please
>   relocate

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong url. The url you're using points to the **web** access provided by ViewVC, not the svn repository.

If you check the url http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/ you'll see that the repository itself is accessible via these urls:

[svn://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/trunk/mono](http://svn://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/trunk/mono)

http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/trunk/mono

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it's telling you to append a `/` to the URL you're now using, right after src -- have you tried that?

Edit: now *I* tried and checked carefully to make sure that's indeed the problem -- but it doesn't get you a solution; at least the svn 1.4.4 I have (it seems) strips the trailing slash from the `svo co` even if you specify it. svn's problems with trailing slash URLs were supposed to be resolved several minor versions ago, but it looks like that's not necessarily true:-(.  [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is down right now so I can't research how to get past that trailing-slash problem...:-(

Do you maybe have some alternative SVN client you could try...?

Comment: yep, as per my edit (didn't see your comment as I was off trying it out) it definitely looks like a svn problem with trailing slashes. If we're lucky it's a client-side issue and you can try an alternative client... (I only have command-line 1.4.4 installed). Or maybe the svnbook site will help when it's back up. In any case it seems worth contacting the projects' owners/admins -- with that trailing slash redirect they're cutting themselves off from no doubt several (maybe all?) would-be downloaders, they should fix it!

Comment: This was my thoughts exactly after I tried again after reading your answer.  MY client is 1.5+ so its not fixed in that either - and simmilarly doesnt work in the copy of tortoise SVN, which is up to date (mostly).

Answer (score 1):

It is problem of Apache configuration described in

http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#301-error

Answer (score 0):

I used http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/trunk/bitsharp/, with success.