# Checking out an SVN repository visible on the web

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

If an SVN repository is viewable on the web, where the engine exposing it is [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/), can it be checked out?

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ViewVC is for webaccess and is completely different from the url that you use for checking out.

In fact, ViewVC even has remote repo access for SVN, in which case the remote repo is specified in the ViewVC and you get web access.

Also see here : [Trying to SVN Checkout Open Source BitSharp Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042214/trying-to-svn-checkout-open-source-bitsharp-library)

Comment: If that is the case, see follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121303/how-to-download-a-repository-exposed-on-the-web-with-viewvc