# Download an SVN repository exposed by ViewVC

Tags: svn, download

Is there a simple way to download an SVN repository that is exposed on the web using [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/)?

Comment: FYI: VisualSVN Server's web UI has the Download button to download folders in the form of ZIP file. You can try this on the demo server at https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/view/head/subversion/trunk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways this question could be interpreted, but the short answer for both is no:

ViewVC is meant to be a repository viewer, so there is no option to download all the files in a section through the web browser.  It might be possible to write a script to do this, but that would take a very long time I imagine, especially if taking into account folder structures.

If you mean that you want to download the actual dump of the repository, the answer would still be no because the repository folder would be stored either locally on the machine, or somewhere ViewVC could locate it.  If you know where the file is, anyway, you could just use a repository browser (such as TortoiseSVN on Windows) to view it and download from said browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ViewVC allows you to download the (recursive) contents on any *directory* within a repository, but not the whole repository itself. (This may not matter much if you e.g. just want the latest trunk version of a project, located at `<repository root>/trunk/`.)

From ViewVC configuration:

> ViewVC can generate a tarball
>   (.tar.gz) from a repository on the
>   fly.  This option allows (you/anyone)
>   to download a tarball of the current
>   directory.
>
> Allow automatic tarball generation? [Yes / No]

To get to this option on Ubuntu/Debian, you'd simply do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure viewvc` (right now I'm not sure about other platforms).

Comment: hrr... I meant how to download a repository exposed *by someone else* using ViewVC. I don't have access to his system :)