# How to download all files from Chrome Extensions example (subversion repo)?

Tags: svn, google-chrome-extension

I would like to download [this examples](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/). They are shown using ViewVC (which I believe is related to subversion) and it seems that there is no easy way of downloading from there, according to this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6121303/1814970) (but the answers are from 2011).

Is there any way to easily access those files? I don't mind command line tools.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every extension example in the source code is available as a zip file as well, directly linked at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.

If you compare the paths, you'll surely notice a pattern:

- [`trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/inspector`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/)
  [`https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/tabs/inspector.zip`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/tabs/inspector.zip)
- [`trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/pin`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/pin/)
  [`https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/tabs/pin.zip`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/tabs/pin.zip)
- [`trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/screenshot`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/screenshot/)
  [`https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/tabs/screenshot.zip`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/tabs/screenshot.zip)

Comment: Haven't checked that link, just the other one to the repo. Thanks!